# How to get data from firebase map object?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to get data from a map object from Firebase and display it on the screen. The issue is that I can't handle whatever I'm receiving from Firebase as a map. I've checked "InstanceOf Map, Array and Object". It gives a true on object and false on the others.
This is how I'm saving the data to Firebase

```
async function handleAddToWatchList() {
    const watchListSnapshot = await watchlistRef
      .where("userId", "==", email)
      .get();
    const watchlistId = watchListSnapshot.docs[0].id;
    const documentRef = watchlistRef.doc(watchlistId);

    documentRef.set(
      {
        tvShows: {
          [data.name]: {
            title: data.name,
            overview: show.overview,
            backdrop: "http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500" + data.backdrop_path,
          },
        },
      },
      { merge: true }
    );
  }
```

When I log the data I receive from Firebase it looks like this

```
Object {
  "Breach": Object {
    "backdrop": "http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/nz8xWrTKZzA5A7FgxaM4kfAoO1W.jpg",
    "overview": "A hardened mechanic must stay awake and maintain an interstellar ark fleeing the dying planet Earth with a few thousand lucky souls on board... the last of humanity. Unfortunately, humans are not the only passengers. A shapeshifting alien creature has taken residence, its only goal is to kill as many people as possible. The crew must think quickly to stop this menace before it destroys mankind.",
    "release": "2020-12-17",
    "title": "Breach",
  },
  "Wonder Woman 1984": Object {
    "backdrop": "http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/srYya1ZlI97Au4jUYAktDe3avyA.jpg",
    "overview": "Wonder Woman comes into conflict with the Soviet Union during the Cold War in the 1980s and finds a formidable foe by the name of the Cheetah.",
    "release": "2020-12-16",
    "title": "Wonder Woman 1984",
  },
}
```

How do i iterate over this to display it on the screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried a for in loop? You can take a look at them here => https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in

Since you have nested objects you probably have to use a for in loop inside another for in loop, so you can loop through the parent object and then through each object.

```
 const parentObject = {
  "Breach": {
    "backdrop": "http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/nz8xWrTKZzA5A7FgxaM4kfAoO1W.jpg",
    "overview": "A hardened mechanic must stay awake and maintain an interstellar ark fleeing the dying planet Earth with a few thousand lucky souls on board... the last of humanity. Unfortunately, humans are not the only passengers. A shapeshifting alien creature has taken residence, its only goal is to kill as many people as possible. The crew must think quickly to stop this menace before it destroys mankind.",
    "release": "2020-12-17",
    "title": "Breach",
  },
  "Wonder Woman 1984": {
    "backdrop": "http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/srYya1ZlI97Au4jUYAktDe3avyA.jpg",
    "overview": "Wonder Woman comes into conflict with the Soviet Union during the Cold War in the 1980s and finds a formidable foe by the name of the Cheetah.",
    "release": "2020-12-16",
    "title": "Wonder Woman 1984",
  },
}

//iterating parent object
for(let property in parentObject){
  //iterating nested objects
  for(let key in parentObject[property]){
    console.log(parentObject[property][key]);
  }
}


/////////OUTPUT: (values of the keys of the nested objects)

http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/nz8xWrTKZzA5A7FgxaM4kfAoO1W.jpg

A hardened mechanic must stay awake and maintain an interstellar ark fleeing the dying planet Earth with a few thousand lucky souls on board... the last of humanity. Unfortunately, humans are not the only passengers. A shapeshifting alien creature has taken residence, its only goal is to kill as many people as possible. The crew must think quickly to stop this menace before it destroys mankind.

2020-12-17

Breach

http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/srYya1ZlI97Au4jUYAktDe3avyA.jpg

Wonder Woman comes into conflict with the Soviet Union during the Cold War in the 1980s and finds a formidable foe by the name of the Cheetah.

2020-12-16

Wonder Woman 1984
```